# Can someone explain me "Design for self" , "Design by copy", and "Design by research" terminologies?

Tags: design-patterns, user-experience

While researching for design questions, I came across these three terminologies, but I am not sure if I have completely understood the meaning. Can someone with more experience please expand the terms ?

1. This is what I have so far :

   1. "Design for self" : Designer assumes the customer is just like
      him
   2. "Design by copy" : ???
   3. "Design by research" : A lot many design decisions will be
      taken only after abundant user-data. (Based on user data design
      decisions will be taken)

So those who are voting to close this question think that these terminologies don't exist ? Are you sure Really  ?
May be want-close people can't just accept there is some UX design terminologies/lingo which  they dont know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an interview question, I think they are looking for the advantages and/or drawbacks of each of these.  Here's what I would say:

1. Design for Self: You have the right definition.  This is the quickest and easiest option of the 3 you presented.  The pitfall here is that you most likely do not represent the full user base of your application, and so you will miss out on the users that think differently than you.
2. Desing by Copy: You design your application by copying features from competing applications or other applications that provide similar functionality.  Again, this is fast and easy to do, and if the feature you are copying is not core to your application, it can be acceptable.  There are, however, (at least) two problems here:

   1. You need to differentiate your product from its competitors, which you cannot do by simply copying them
   2. The application you are copying from does not necessarily target the same user base as your application, and therefore it may not address all of the needs of your users
3. Design by Research: You design you application after identifying your target user-base and conducting research into their needs.  Additionally, you may study how several different designs meet their needs through focus groups, observational research, and prototyping.  This is the most time-consuming and most expensive option, but it often yields the best results.

Comment: To add another disadvantage to #2, if you design by copy, you have to worry about copyright infringment.